# Proper setup of Oracle Environment variables for PHP, MDB2, and OCI8

Tags: php, oracle11g, fedora, oci8

I've set up a Fedora 19 server, with Oracle 11g, PHP 5.5.4, Apache 2.4.6, and PEAR 1.9.4. In addition to this, I have the OCI8 plug-in for PHP downloaded and enabled, and have downloaded MDB2 and the MDB2_Driver_oci8.

However, there are problems with the setup - an old website from an older server doesn't work on it, so it seems the culprit is an improperly setup Oracle environment for Apache, and oci8.

The Oracle 11g Database itself, however, works fine - I've been able to log in as SYSTEM, create a new user, and restore a database to said user.

Below is a screenshot from the Environment of the new Fedora 19 server, using phpinfo():

[image: New Server]

Below is a screenshot of the Environment of the older Fedora server:

[image]

There's a lot, but probably the only important things there are the ones concerning Oracle.

I followed [link here](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/09/27/oracle-11g-xe-on-fedora/) tutorial on how to install Oracle 11g on Fedora, and I was able to get it up and running, albeit I have to run `. /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh` every time I start up.

But whereas in the old server, it shows up in the Environment (in phpinfo()), in the new server, it does not.

Of note is that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set in both, but I had to to add it manually in the httpd file (/etc/sysconfig/) by adding the following in it:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/u01/apps/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib export
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH

But if I echo out LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the newer server, it returns nothing. In the older server, it returns what is displayed in the Environment page.

What's going on here? How do I fix this? And is there any other Oracle-related thing I missed?

Thanks to any and all who will help.